# Apache Error While Import .war file. "Error: FAIL - Application at context path [/folder] could not be started"

Tags: apache, deployment, runtime-error, war

After deploying the war file from apache server it shows the Running status fail. Then I deploying the .war file its shows error like **FAIL - Application at context path [/folder] could not be started**. How can I solve this issue and how can I run my war file in Apache server. Kindly guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need a java server to run war files.  A common way to integrate this with Apache is to run your war file in a java server such as tomcat or wildfly, then with apache, reverse proxy to your java server using a virtual host.  This way apache works as your gateway interface, then the java server actually handles your logic for your specific application.

Unless you are using Apache Tomcat?  If so, please provide more context.  What server are using and what are the logs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Apache server version 9.0.12. Getting error like "SEVERE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.delete [filepath/] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems."

Comment: What files did it fail to delete?  And where are they?

Comment: An error shows in log file like "One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file". How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you describe how you are deploying your server?

Comment: I'm deploying the war file via Apache server. While deploying it its shows error like false status. While I will check in error log file its shows error like "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start.". What kind of issue is this? how can I solve this issue.?